# httpContext.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.DataTokens throws Null Reference exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqlite, mocking

I'm trying to write an unit test(using NUnit & MOQ) for a method which uses `MockHttpContext` from the test method like so:
[image]
However, `httpContext.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.DataTokens` throws null-reference exception because `RouteData` is null. I'm initializing `RequestContext` like the screenshot below:

[image]

What should I do to avoid this error?

Comment: the route data or token is null. To avoid the error populate all the members that are accessed during the test.

Answer (score 0):

It's obvious that you need to init not only `RequestContext`.
You need to init `HttpContext` and all sub fileds to `DataTokens`
or

1. You need to create a mock for an object that returns `DataTokens`
2. Create a mock for the `RouteData` object and `Setup` `GetValue` method for this mock to return the `DataTokens` for a step above
3. ... Do the same for all objects: `RequestContext`, `Request`, `HttpContext`.